# How to manually upload code to AWS Lightsail Node.js instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I have created a Node.js instance on AWS Lightsail. Everything works ok, I can connect to it via SSH (tried through the browser) and I can access the static HTML index when navigating to the static IP. I now would like to deploy my code and run my application...but I cannot find a reference on how to do it. I do NOT wish to use docker images. The code is not hosted in a GitHub repo and will never be. Is there a way to manually upload code the instance? Even one file at the time would work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lightsail creates for you simple virtual instance. To transfer files there you can use SSH file transfer, using SCP connection.

Start here: https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-ssh-using-terminal
This guide will make sure you can connect to your instance with terminal.

Then, use the key pair to configure SCP client, like CyberDuck or WinSCP, and start copying files like on casual FTP server :-)